# cannot start react server

Tags: reactjs, npm

Please help!

I want to learn react. I use node.js version 12.16.1 and make new react app with this command:
npx create-react-app my-aps

then, i move into my-aps folder and type npm start.

[I got this error message on the command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7noDn.jpg)

this is the log :
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

```
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Malik\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle my-aps@0.1.0~prestart: my-aps@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle my-aps@0.1.0~start: my-aps@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-aps@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-aps@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Malik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Malik\my-aps\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Files\cpp\bin\Intel64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\libnvvp;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;C:\cuda\bin;C:\cuda\lib\x64;C:\sqlite3;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\IBM\SPSS\Statistics\25\JRE\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Malik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\Malik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\Malik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Malik\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Users\Malik\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle my-aps@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Malik\my-aps
10 silly lifecycle my-aps@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-aps@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-aps@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: my-aps@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Malik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Malik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-aps@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Malik\my-aps
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Malik\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error my-aps@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the my-aps@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npm install` and run again using `npm run start`

Comment: Have you followed the steps which are shown in terminal?

Comment: yes, i also used yarn too and it still resulting the same error

Comment: hey, thanks for responsing, i just solved the issue. I deleted the node_modules in user folder